# How to get Max() with potential null?

Tags: .net, linq, c#-4.0

I'm running the following query but it fails with the exception:

*The cast to value type 'Int32' failed because the materialized value is null.*

```
var myvalue = conn.Employees.Where(r => r.LastName == LastName).Max(r1 => r1.Id);
```

Is there a way to get the Max() and also consider nulls in one line of code?

Comment: Is the property `Id` a `Nullable<int>`?

Comment: @Jehof That wouldn't make any sense if it wasn't. It would be 0.

Comment: @gleng how do you know that? His question is not clear and for me it is missing information to give a valid answer.

Comment: I've updated my answer @4thSpace. Check it out.

Comment: 1) Is this LINQ-to-objects? Or some other flavour of LINQ? 2) Are you sure the issue is in your query? If this is one of the `IQueryable` based LINQ flavours the problem might be caused by your classes not matching the database. For example the database might contain `null`, but `Id` is a non-nullable property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of coallesce assuming Id is a nullable
or expand the where-condition :

```
// Coallesce- probably not the best thing here
var myvalue = conn.Employees.Where(r => r.LastName == LastName).Max(r1 => r1.Id ?? 0);

// Expanded where-condition
var myvalue = conn.Employees.Where(r => r!= null && r.Id!=null && r.LastName == LastName).Max(r1 => r1.Id);
```

Note that myvalue can be null also. 
So if you do something like this:

```
int someInt = (int) myvalue;
```

Youll get an exception obviously.

So a Fix could be:

```
int someInt =(int) ( myvalue ?? 0 );
```

Comment: Then its not the linq-expression that causes the error or you didnt provide enough info in your question.